# How do I turn off logging beforeSave afterSave hooks in parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, parse-platform

How do I turn off logging beforeSave afterSave, and other cloud hooks in Parse.  I have lots of logging going on that I do not want to see.

beforeSave and afterSave hooks show ALL their inputs and outputs.  So if you have a cloud function that returns a long list of users or something, their console logging becomes kinda useless...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Someone from Parse can chime in if I'm wrong. The traditional answer is: log everything and use a good log reader to filter out what you are not interested in. Parse.com is, IMHO, a "light-weight" development/execution environment. Last time I used it, you could not download the raw log files.

Curiously, an entire industry has grown up around making better and better log viewers. One vendor (http://www.splunk.com/) has even incorporated machine learning to help administrators separate the wheat from the chaff in their log files.